# Flash socket server only works on local machine

Tags: php, flash, sockets

I have created a basic flash socket server in PHP, it all works fine on my local machine (both in the browser and in the flash sandbox) but as soon as I get another machine to connect to my computer's Site directory, they can't get a connection open to the server!

In flash:

```
mySocket.connect("localhost",9999);
```

In PHP

```
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 9999;
```

I have tried changing the flash code to the IP of my machine but then none of the clients (including the local) can connect.

Please help!

> PS. Running on a mac in the Sites dir.
>   I am running the socket server through
>   terminal (PHP 5). Am running a policy file server with perl but I don't think that is the problem

Comment: what server are you using on the production/alternate server?

Comment: what do you mean? I am running Apache and my own PHP socket server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"127.0.0.1" is the address for the loopback interface. It's only available on the same machine. You need to listen on all interfaces (loopback, eth0, etc) by binding the socket to "0.0.0.0".

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly, for the record I also had to change the flash code from localhost to the ip of the local machine :)